# Overflow Error for Python C++ Extension Module

Tags: python, c++, integer-overflow

I am writing a simple bitshift addition function. It works for 64-bit integer values when I compile in C. However, when I try to build a C++ extension module in Python I get the following error for values >2^32 - 1:

`OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum`

My full code for the extension module is below:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *method_bitadd(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    unsigned long long x;
    unsigned long long y;
    unsigned long long and_op;
    unsigned long long or_op; 

    /* Parse arguments */
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "KK", &x, &y)){
            return NULL;
    }

    //And operation 
    and_op=(x&y);

    if(and_op==0){
        or_op=(x|y);
        return PyLong_FromUnsignedLongLong(or_op);
    }

    while(and_op > 0){
        or_op=(x|y);
        x=(and_op<<1);
        y=(~and_op&or_op);
        and_op=(x&y);
    }

    or_op=(x|y);

    return PyLong_FromUnsignedLongLong(or_op);
}

static PyMethodDef bitaddMethods[] = {
    {"bitadd", method_bitadd, METH_VARARGS, "Python interface for bitadd C library function"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef myaddmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "bitadd",
    "Python interface for the bit_add C library function",
    -1,
    bitaddMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_bitadd(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&myaddmodule);
}
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, read [ask], since you're not even asking a question!

Comment: Please add the calling Python code.